# how to access to asptable in runtime

Tags: asp.net

i have a table in my Update Panel that created dynamically in runtime with this code:

```
Table tblmain = new Table();
TableRow tblrow = new TableRow();
TableCell tblcell = new TableCell();
tblmain.Rows.Add(tblrow);
myDiv.Controls.Add(tblmain);
```

now i want to access to this table. but when i try to do this work by this code:

```
Table tbl = (Table)myDiv.Controls[0];
```

i receive this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table'.

why asptable convert to literalcontrol?

Comment: What else is in `myDiv`?  It sounds like the very first thing in the `Controls` collection is a `LiteralControl` and not a `Table`.  Put a debugging breakpoint there and examine what's actually in the `Controls` collection to see where your `Table` is.

Comment: in this collection has 3 controls. but when i change control index number (Controls[1]or [2]) so i receive above error.

Comment: What are the three controls in the collection?  Is there a `Table` in there at all when that code runs?

Comment: two label and one table. that known as literal control.

Comment: i use the foreach and "if;is" command. but don't true my condition.

Answer (score 0):

Give `ID` to your table and use `FindControl` to get this table without using loops:

```
tblmain.ID = "tblMain";
tblmain.ClientID = "tblMain";
...
Table tbl = (Table)myDiv.FindControl("tblMain");
```

Comment: i test this but my issue was not solved. only when control is creating this control is accessible!!!

Comment: In which event-handler/function it is not accessible ? Post that code and also _div's_ generated html you get in browser using View source. Place breakpoint at `myDiv.Controls` and see what your div's `Controls` collection holds.

Comment: after render the page,for example when click a button for access to tblMain, that not work. but wen place code for create table in button it's work correctly.

Comment: after click the button and break point on myDiv.Controls table was exist on browser but in source mode i could not found the myDiv and myTbl.